# RecyclerView EmptyView has RecyclerItem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I'm trying to set my empty view has a recycler item so that the empty state can move up and down a little bit.

I have set created 2 adapters. One which binds a list of items and the other will bind simple text to say the list is empty. My problem is in updateUI(), the EmptyAdapter() returns null because i'm not sure how to use the constructor. There are no data items I need to bind, just inflate the view.

Looks specifically at the method and class:

```
updateUI(),
EmptyAdapter(),
CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes)
```

My issue is with EmptyAdapter returning null in updateUI()

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private CrimeAdapter mCrimeAdapter;
private EmptyAdapter mEmptyAdapter;
private ImageView mSolvedImage;
private boolean subtitleVisible;
private static final int REQUEST_CRIME = 1;
private String SUBTITLE = "subtitle";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle
        savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime_list, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        subtitleVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SUBTITLE);
    }

    updateUI();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable(SUBTITLE, subtitleVisible);
}


private void updateUI() {
    //Singleton
    CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
    //List of crimes from singleton
    List<Crime> crimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();


    if (crimes.size() != 0) {
        //If adapter null, populate list
        if (mCrimeAdapter == null) {
            mCrimeAdapter = new CrimeAdapter(crimes);
            //hook-up adapter to recycler view
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCrimeAdapter);
        } else {

            //else we are updating list b/c of some change in the data
            mCrimeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } else {
        if (mEmptyAdapter == null) {
            mEmptyAdapter = new EmptyAdapter();
            //hook-up empty adapter to recycler view
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mEmptyAdapter);
        } else {
            mEmptyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    //Update subtitle upon completing a crime and return to CrimeListActivity
    updateSubtitle();
}


//VIEW-HOLDER & ADAPTER FOR RECYCLER-VIEW

private class EmptyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView emptyView;

    public EmptyHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_view1, parent, false));
        emptyView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.emptyTextView);
    }

    public void bind() {
        emptyView.setText("NO CRIMES HERE");
        emptyView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}

private class EmptyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EmptyHolder> {

    public EmptyAdapter() {
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public EmptyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        return new EmptyHolder(inflater, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EmptyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind();
    }

}

private class CrimeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTitle;
    private TextView mDate;
    private Crime mCrime;


    public CrimeHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        //pass in itemView to constructor of ViewHolder
        // View heirarchy is now held in ViewHolders 'itemView' field
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, parent, false));
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
        mDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_date);
        mSolvedImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved_image);
    }

    public void bind(Crime crime) {
        mCrime = crime;
        mTitle.setText(mCrime.getTitle());
        mDate.setText(mCrime.getDate().toString());
        mSolvedImage.setVisibility(mCrime.isSolved() ? VISIBLE : GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity.newIntent(getContext(), mCrime.getId());
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CRIME);

    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CRIME) {
        //handle result
    }
}

private class CrimeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CrimeHolder> {

    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public CrimeAdapter(List<Crime> crimes) {
        mCrimes = crimes;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CrimeHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());


        return new CrimeHolder(inflater, parent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CrimeHolder holder, int position) {
        Crime crime = mCrimes.get(position);
        holder.bind(crime);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCrimes.size();
    }

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    updateUI();
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);

    MenuItem subtitle = menu.findItem(R.id.show_subtitle);
    if (subtitleVisible) {
        subtitle.setTitle("Hide Subtitle");
    } else {
        subtitle.setTitle(R.string.show_subtite);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_crime:
            Crime crime = new Crime();
            CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).addCrime(crime);
            Intent intent = CrimePagerActivity
                    .newIntent(getContext(), crime.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.show_subtitle:
            subtitleVisible = !subtitleVisible;
            //RE-CREATES options menu, resulting in menu item text change
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            updateSubtitle();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void updateSubtitle() {
    String subtitle;
    CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
    int crimeCount = crimeLab.getCrimes().size();
    if (subtitleVisible) {
        subtitle = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.subtitle_plural, crimeCount, crimeCount);
    } else {
        subtitle = "Criminal Intent";
    }
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(subtitle);
}
```

}

Comment: why you need adapter for display only one empty text ? that is " Use a sledgehammer to crack a nut"

Comment: To learn..lets say I remove the EmptyAdapter(), then CrimeAdapter must extend RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>.  Is that the approach your suggesting?

Comment: yes, I means we should only using CrimeAdapter, and remove EmptyAdapter because it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out one issue, in your empty adapter, your code

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

so nothing be show, if you want show your empty text, please using

```
@Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: WOW!!! So easy....

So I trust that the somewhere in RecyclerView.java class there is logic which tells the adapter there are NO ITEMS TO SHOW when getItemCount() returns 0?

Comment: yes, document said: "this method returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter"

Answer (score 0):

Use the adapterview.setEmptyView(View)

Android handles all of this for you.

Note that your empty view must be in the same layout file.

Comment: from what i've read RecyclerView does not have a setEmptyView(), that was on listView. I've seen other people's libraries that implement their own setEmptyView(). Let me know if I'm wrong

Comment: After further review, you are correct. The setEmptyView() method is from the adapterView class. Which is not a parent class of recyclerview. Thanks for pointing that out.